# Finding $\dfrac{1}{1+\tan 70^{\circ}}+\dfrac{1}{1+\tan 20^{\circ}}$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, trigonometry

> find the :
>   $$\dfrac{1}{1+\tan 70^{\circ}}+\dfrac{1}{1+\tan 20^{\circ}}$$

My Try :
$$\dfrac{1}{1+\dfrac{\sin 70^{\circ}}{\cos 70^{\circ}}}+\dfrac{1}{1+\dfrac{\sin 20^{\circ}}{\cos 20^{\circ}}}$$

$$\dfrac{\cos70^{\circ}}{\cos 70^{\circ}+\sin 70^{\circ}}+\dfrac{\cos20^{\circ}}{\cos 20^{\circ}+\sin 20^{\circ}}$$

now what do i do ?

Comment: $\cos20=\sin70$

Comment: $$\frac{1}{1+z}+\frac{1}{1+\frac{1}{z}}=1.$$

Answer (score 3):

Let $x=20^{\circ}$

\begin{eqnarray}\dfrac{1}{1+\tan 70^{\circ}}+\dfrac{1}{1+\tan 20^{\circ}}&=&\dfrac{1}{1+\cot 20^{\circ}}+\dfrac{1}{1+\tan 20^{\circ}}\\&=& \dfrac{\sin x}{\sin x+\cos x}+\dfrac{\cos x}{\cos x+\sin x}\\ &=&1\end{eqnarray}

Answer (score 2):

It's $$\dfrac{\sin20^{\circ}}{\sin 20^{\circ}+\cos 20^{\circ}}+\dfrac{\cos20^{\circ}}{\cos 20^{\circ}+\sin 20^{\circ}}=1$$

Answer (score 2):

$$\frac { 1 }{ 1+\tan { { 70 }^{ \circ  } }  } +\frac { 1 }{ 1+\tan { { 20 }^{ \circ  } }  } =\frac { 1 }{ 1+\tan { { 70 }^{ \circ  } }  } +\frac { 1 }{ 1+\cot { { 70 }^{ \circ  } }  } =\\ =\frac { 1 }{ 1+\tan { { 70 }^{ \circ  } }  } +\frac { 1 }{ 1+\frac { 1 }{ \tan { { 70 }^{ \circ  } }  }  } =\frac { 1+\tan { { 70 }^{ \circ  } }  }{ 1+\tan { { 70 }^{ \circ  } }  } =1$$

Answer (score 2):

> See that $$\tan (x) = \frac{\sin x}{\cos x}=\frac{\cos (90^{\circ}-x)}{\sin (90^{\circ}-x)}=\frac{1}{\tan (90^{\circ}-x)}$$
>   what happen if you take $x=70$

$$\dfrac{1}{1+\tan 70^{\circ}}+\dfrac{1}{1+\tan 20^{\circ}} = \dfrac{1}{1+\frac{1}{\tan 20^{\circ}}}+\dfrac{1}{1+\tan 20^{\circ}}= \dfrac{\tan 20^{\circ}}{1+\tan 20^{\circ}}+\dfrac{1}{1+\tan 20^{\circ}} = 1$$